# Meeting one's child in the past

Tags: time-travel

I'm writing a story where the hero in his 20s ends up in the past and meets his father (also in his 20s), but does not recognise him due to certain appearance alterations. The father in his turn has children in his 30s (10 years after this encounter). I wonder if the father should be able to recognize the man he met in his 20s in his grown up son by the time the son reaches puberty or adulthood?

**EDIT:**
While I am satisfied and incredibly grateful with all the answers and input I have received, I feel there is a need for some clarity in my question. While I wouldn't want the father to recognize the son, I also do not want to end up writing a story that bends certain rules or goes around common sense in order to lead the narrative through the desired course.
Aside from that, the father keeps meeting his son several times throughout somewhat a year. As a matter of fact they are rivals, as the father is a villain and the son is a secondary "good" character in this story. They are on the opposite sides of the story and manage to piss each other off by the time the son returns back to the future.

Comment: This seems like a matter of, do you want him to be able to? People can sometimes recognize relatives, and sometimes don't.

Comment: How much time did the father spend with his time-traveled son? How memorable was it? Although there's probably still no definitive answer to this, there's not even a hope of a guess if the interaction between father and son is completely unspecified.

Comment: Argh, I don't find back the other question which had kinda the same issue... Oh well ^^". As far as I read it, it's extremely circumstance and character-based : If the initial meeting was very brief, there's no chance. But if they spent a long time together, it's likely they would notice the similarities with their past "friend". And I'm disregarding time-travel paradoxes which might alter the future kid appearance from the kid who travelled back in time ^^. The good point in this, it's that you're free to choose whichever way you want to go, it's just a matter of adding some story elements!

Comment: When his son loses his nose in an accident and has the jade one made, then I think the father will recognize him as the stranger with the jade nose he met long ago.  Prosthetic jade noses are not something you see every day.  Maybe in your story jade prosthesis are more common, but this particular nose is made with fairly dramatic styling choices so unusual even among the jade nosed-set.

Comment: Son, I told you not to ask about this in public. If you keep doing this sort of thing, the ripples you create could wreck the timeline we're building for our descendants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I'm going to vote no**

As others have mentioned, you have the ability to choose, as the worldbuilder (and the story writer) whether or not anyone recognizes anything. This is called *poetic license.*

> The literary term poetic license is a thing of many names that comes in many forms. Also known as artistic license, literary license, dramatic license, historical license, narrative licence, licentia poetica, or just simply license, poetic license is a conversational term (or sometimes a euphemism).
>
> The term comes from Latin. Poetic derives from the Latin poeta, which means "poet" or "maker." License comes from the Latin licentia, which means "to be permitted." Basically, poetic license involves the departure of facts or even rules for language in order to create a different effect, usually dramatic, for a piece of work or speech. ([Source](https://owlcation.com/humanities/What-is-Poetic-License-Definition-and-Examples))

In other words, whether the man could or couldn't — whether scientifically he could or couldn't — you as the author have the right to do whatever you please to make your story work.

**So why do I vote no?**

Here's the problem. You meet a guy. Let's say you get to know him well! You invite him over for dinner. You shoot pool with him. For a solid year of your life, you see him on nearly a daily basis. Then he leaves.

Nine months later this amazing miracle is born. A baby! Like all babies, this baby doesn't look anything at all like his 20-year-old self. He's really good at digesting food, not particularly good at sleeping, and has the entire market on drawing your attention completely cornered.

*And that's the problem.*

Your attention (unless you're a scallywag and a scoundrel) is focused on that child.

*For twenty years.*

Even if you're one of those dads who starts loosing interest by the child's 8th birthday and can't relate at all to the bundle of raging hormones we call fifteen. You're basically spending 7,305 days with your child, watching him change day by day. By age sixteen you can barely remember what he looked like at age ten without looking at a photograph.

At age twenty, the odds of you recognizing the face that knocks on your door as *that one guy* you played pool with twenty years previously... that would be really impressive, because the face before you is *your son,* the only person who's owned that face. The other guy's face is a blur that your memory is further blurring in favor of the reality standing before you asking for the keys to the car. Heck, I can remember some of the people I knew at age twenty, but not all of them. Not even some I remember (quite literally) playing pool with. Not clearly. Why would I?

*Unless god, you know, my author... deemed that I had one of "those kinds of memories."*

And that's the value of poetic license.

**But maybe another way of looking at this will help...**

Let's say my son visits me from the future, not for a year, but for a single day. It's an important day, whatever it is, and eventful. One that might create a memory or two. And part of those memories are...

- The green shirt that guy was wearing that day.
- The smell of his cologne.
- The cut of his hair.
- An odd stain on the left leg of his jeans.
- And a particularly nice jacket.

And suddenly that same guy (now back in the "present") knocks on my door and thanks to the odd nature of memory I suddenly realize...

- The guy I remember wearing a green shirt is wearing it because he stayed at my house last night and borrowed it from my wardrobe that morning.
- The cologne also happens to be mine.
- He said he was going to get a hair cut before meeting me at the door just now.
- The stain on his jeans was from dribbling the BBQ I'd made him the night before, he couldn't get it washed out before leaving.
- And the jacket was a gift for his birthday last week (oh, the paradox *that* would be!).

And all those odd events wouldn't make any sense *at all* until that moment when my son gets back from traveling to the past and suddenly that memory causes all the little bits of previously irrelevant information to come together into the realization that I'd met my 20-year-old son twenty years before.

*Poetic license...*

Which is *totally off-topic* on this stack because we don't answer storybuilding questions. So why am I answering your question?

**Because what you're doing, right now, is establishing the rules of time travel in your world. And this is one way those rules can be established — but it's really important as you continue to use this Stack that you understand the difference. Worldbuilding is about the stage where any play may take place. We don't answer questions about the plays themselves.**

Fair warning. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate answer! I realize how this question balances between storybuilding and worldbuilding, but you are also right when you say that I am trying to establish rules of time travel in my world. It is not about what course the narrative is going to take, but how human psychology would work if time travel were possible. For future reference, what site on stack exchange should I use for similar questions? Thank you once again. This answer has made things clear and I understand now how to proceed forward

Comment: @CannotCode There isn't another Stack. A "Storybuilding" Stack has been considered many times and fails each time because it violates to too great a degree the basic precepts of Stack Exchange, notably that questions should lead to one reasonably objective answer. Storybuilding cannot do that (Worldbuilding barely can do that). Consequently, as you ask questions, you need to strip the story from the question. In other words, if the question can be universally applied to any story that takes place in the world, it's on-topic. That's actually a good exercise for you, the author, (\*continued\*)

Comment: ... because learning to separate the world from the story will ultimately create a better world and a better story. It's difficult to consistently apply world rules to multiple stories if they're not well separated. One way of separating the two is to realize the difference between things that happen to characters and character choices. Ultimately, this is why I chose to answer your question rather than vote to close it. You were not asking about a character choice... but I hope you can see now how close you came to that line. The art of asking a question here is sometimes delicate.

Answer (score 1):

I would say so but he probably wouldn't know it was his son and think them looking alike was a amazing coincidence and tell the kid stories [if the meeting was more than once] about the guy he met that looked just like his son. Or maybe not and he would just get this familiar feeling like he's seen it before but knows it the first time since he didn't meet his son before this. (or so he thinks)